# javascript debugging: Is there a way to break on assignment of a specific value (to any variable)?

Tags: javascript, debugging, breakpoints, watch, developer-tools

Similar in some sense to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910623/javascript-debugging-is-there-a-way-to-break-on-a-change-of-variable-value), but rather than waiting for any change in a particular variable, this would be by value: breaking on a particular primitive value (probably only particularly useful for numbers and strings) being assigned.

e.g. When watching for assignment of value 'asdf' (in some browser's dev tools or something like Firebug):

```
function example(){
  var x = 'as';
  x += 'df'; /*break here*/
  return x;
}
y= example(); /*break here, as well*/
```

I suspect that the answer is that this doesn't exist (searching has turned up nothing), but just in case, I thought I'd ask.